# Kronecker Product Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, kronecker-product

Is there an Kronecker Product Identity that allows for factorisation?

If $\textbf{A},\textbf{B}$ are $50\times50$ dim-matrices (B is diagonal), and $\textbf{C},\textbf{D}$ are $100\times100$ dim-matrices (D is diagonal). Normally I would do $$R=A^TB\otimes C^TD$$ where R is a $5000\times5000$ dim-matrix.

Is there a way to factorise out the $D$ matrix like, $$R=D(A^TB\otimes C^TI)$$ where I is $100\times100$ dim-matrix.

The reason is that I have an algorithm where only $D$ changes at each iteration, whilst the others are constant.
$$\textbf{for n 0 to N:}\quad\quad\quad$$
$$\quad R_n=A^TB\otimes C^TD_n$$
$$\text{stuff}...$$

Thus, it would be be computationally quicker calculating the matrices and then looping only doing 1 multiplication. I thought maybe turning $D$ into $5000\times5000$, then doing element wise multiplication, that would be:
$$\textbf{C} = (\textbf{A}^T\textbf{B}\otimes \textbf{C}^T\textbf{I})$$
$$\textbf{for n 0 to N:}\quad\quad\quad$$
$$\quad \textbf{R_n}=\textbf{D}_n^{new}\text{*} \textbf{C}$$
$$\text{stuff}...$$
where * is element multiplication, and $\textbf{D}_n^{new}$ is $5000\times5000$ (that is $D$ repeated 50 by 50 times), but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The standard mixed product rule yields
$$\eqalign{ R = (A^T B)\otimes(C^T D) \,=\, (A^T B\otimes C^T )\,(I_{50}\otimes D) }$$
The matrix on the far RHS has a block-diagonal structure with a constant diagonal term (i.e. the $D$ matrix) repeated 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\m{\times}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Let $I_n\in\R{n\m n}$ denote the identity matrix
and $\,K^{(m,n)}\in\R{mn\m mn}\:$ the [Commutation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix)
and $\,\{A,B\}$ arbitrary matrices with dimensions
$$\eqalign{
&A \in\R{m\m n} \qquad B\in\R{p\m q} \\
}$$
The Kronecker product can be vectorized as
$$\eqalign{
\vc{A\k B}
 &= \LR{I_n\k K^{(q,m)}\k I_p}\BR{I_m\k I_n\k\vc B}\vc A \\
 &= \LR{I_n\k K^{(q,m)}\k I_p}\BR{\vc A\k I_p\k I_q}\,\vc B \\
}$$
Applying this to the current problem yields
$$\eqalign{
R &= A^TB\k C^TD \\
\vc R &= \BR{I_{50}\k K^{(100,\ 50)}\k I_{100}}
    \BR{\vc{A^TB}\k I_{10000}}\vc D \\
}$$
The matrix on the RHS is large but extremely sparse.